# Configuring TLS certificate for Github Enterprise server

Tags: ssl, ca, github-enterprise

On my Github enterprise when I install the SSL certificate with the key its displaying an error message:

> "Github ssl cert The certificate is not signed by a trusted
>   certificate authority (CA) or the certificate chain is missing
>   intermediate CA signing certificates."

I was given from our certification authority team 4 certificates.

1. SSL certificate : github.pem
2. A set of 3 CA certificates : root, subca and subca2

On my Github enterprise management console, it needs 2 entries

1. A x509 SSL certificate
2. Unencrypted key

I have tried github.pem key alone and with different combination by concatenating CA certificates, but its failing always with the same error.

Is there a pattern to concatenate the certificate?

Any clue how i can resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: having the same issue. Did you solve it ?

Comment: In my case, Github Enterprise server setup on AWS. I am using NLB -> ALB -> target group having ec2 instance hosting github server. Doing ssl termination at ALB using public cert generated by aws acm . Since github server also requires public ssl cert & aws doesn't support exporting public cert,key , I am using let's encrypt public free cert of same host domain on ec2 instance . Github server managemet console provides a automated way to generate/renew lets encrypt ssl cert for instance

Answer (score 6):

Please abide the following steps to add 3 certificates to your .pem file:

1. Open your domain certificate pem file in Notepad ++.
2. Add intermediate (DigiCertCA2.pem) certificate under Domain certificate.
3. Add root certificate (TrustedRoot.pem) to your domain certificate.
4. Save the .pem file that have the following 3 certificates (domain , intermediate, root).
5. Upload the modified certificate.pem file and the private key.
6. click on Save Settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. 
When trying to load the PEM and Key files to GitHub Enterprise I got the same message. The cert was created using the exact same methods as I have done before, but was failing.

Github ssl cert The certificate is not signed by a trusted certificate authority (CA) or the certificate chain is missing intermediate CA signing certificates.

Steps I took:

1. Created a cert for the server (webserver with Private Key)
2. Exported from my users personal store (PFX including all certs in the path and export all extended properties)
3. C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin> openssl.exe pkcs12 -in git_key_included.pfx -nocerts -out priv-key.pem -nodes
4. C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin> openssl.exe pkcs12 -in git_key_included.pfx -nokeys -out cert.pem
5. C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin> openssl rsa -in priv-key.pem -out server.key

I eventually figured it out by opening the PEM using Notepad++. The openssl commands work fine on the old exported cert, but swap around the ordering of the certs on the new exported cert. The broken cert had:

Primary SSL certificate 
Root certificate
Intermediate certificate

Instead of the correct ordering of:

Primary SSL certificate 
Intermediate certificate
Root certificate

So I swapped them around and it worked.

Comment: Thanks !!!! I promote this answer as the best ("So I swapped them around and it worked." is the solution).